# Why is Hugin placing all my images on top of each other?

Tags: panorama, hugin

I'm trying to stitch a panorama using Hugin. I'm letting it automatically choose the control points and it does a very good job at it. However when I look at the panorama preview I see that it just places all the images on top of each other, completely ignoring the control points. Any idea why it does this? For control I also tried stitching the images with Microsoft ICE and that worked with no problems.

**EDIT**

For reference here are two photos from the set:

- [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZDoZ.jpg)
- [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhEQh.jpg)

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24G0P.jpg) is the resulting image stitched with Microsoft ICE.

Comment: It might help to see at least 2 of the images so we can examine the overlap and content characteristics.

Comment: Updated my question with links to images.

Comment: why dont you use ICE then?

Comment: I could, it's just that in the past I've used Hugin plus Hugin has more customization options than ICE.

Comment: @MihaiDamian check out the latest Hugin, it does a much better job finding control point between images. I was able to stitch your sample images together without issues.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you haven't "Aligned" the images.

In the latest version (2013.0.0, released a few weeks after your question was posted) it's a bit simpler / more obvious what to do in the 'Simple' interface mode (the default).

For a lot of simple cases it's a matter of just clicking the 3 buttons in order:

1. Load images...
2. Align...
3. Create Panorama...

Answer (score 1):

Detecting control points is not enough. You need to compute/optimise the camera parameters in the Optimiser tab. You can look at the Hugin documentation for more information: http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_Photos_tab#Optimise